# C++. Why I can't implement interface using trait class?

Tags: c++, arduino

So I want to use a trait class to implement my contract class, is it possible? Because I got some errors when I compile this following code:

code:

```
class MyContract {
public:
    virtual void foo()=0;
};

class TraitClass {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        Serial.println("hello");
    }
};

class MyClass : public virtual MyContract, public TraitClass {
    // MyClass stuff here.
};

void setup()
{
    MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass->foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass` does not implement the pure virtual method declared in the `MyContract` superclass. Just because it also inherits from `TraitClass` doesn't mean that `TraitClass`'s `foo()` is going to implement it.

You need to connect the dots:

```
class MyClass : public virtual MyContract, public TraitClass {


    void foo() override
    {
         TraitClass::foo();
    }
};
```

Comment: I though I can get a cleaner code using this approach. Thank you anyway.